# getting error: "connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?" when trying to create a user with postgresql on centos

Tags: postgresql, centos

complete error:

```
Creating 'pcore' PostgreSQL user... psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Connecting to PostgreSQL as 'pcore'... 
 ** Error occurred during execution: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "pcore"
```

postgresql:

```
psql -U postgres template1
psql (8.4.9)
Type "help" for help.

template1=# \l
                                  List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |  Collation  |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres
                                                             : postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres
                                                             : postgres=CTc/postgres
(3 rows)
```

linux:

```
lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.0-ia32:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-ia32:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-ia32:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS release 5.7 (Final)
Release:    5.7
Codename:   Final
```

also:

```
ps -ef | grep post

user   25055 25032  0 11:13 pts/1    00:00:00 grep post
postgres 32104     1  0 Jan20 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/postmaster -p 5432 -D /var/lib/pgsql/data
```

There is no user pcore in /etc/passwd
Could this be the problem, that postgresql expects one to one matching between linux users and postgresql users ?

I am trying to create a user when this error occurs:

```
# Database imports
import pgdb as psql

# This will create the 'pcore' user using `su` to run the
# command as the postgres system user
def createPsqlPcoreUser(new_pass):
    print "Creating 'pcore' PostgreSQL user...",
    sys.stdout.flush()
    cmd_list = ['su', '-', 'postgres', '-c','psql --host=%s -c '\
        '"CREATE USER pcore WITH PASSWORD \'%s\' CREATEDB"' % \
        (PSQL_SOCKET_PATH, new_pass)]
    p1 = subprocess.Popen(cmd_list,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    p1.wait()
    print p1.communicate()[0]
```

Additionally:

```
 sudo -u postgres createuser pcore -P
Enter password for new role: 
Enter it again: 
Shall the new role be a superuser? (y/n) y
createuser: could not connect to database postgres: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
[root@localhost pcore]# service postgresql status
postmaster (pid 28901 28900 28899 28898 28896 28894) is running...
[root@localhost pcore]# ps -ef | grep post
postgres 28894     1  0 00:21 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/postmaster -p 5432 -D /var/lib/pgsql/data
postgres 28896 28894  0 00:21 ?        00:00:00 postgres: logger process                          
postgres 28898 28894  0 00:21 ?        00:00:00 postgres: writer process                          
postgres 28899 28894  0 00:21 ?        00:00:00 postgres: wal writer process                      
postgres 28900 28894  0 00:21 ?        00:00:00 postgres: autovacuum launcher process             
postgres 28901 28894  0 00:21 ?        00:00:00 postgres: stats collector process
```

Comment: The first error: some application tries to create a (postgres) user, but cannot connect. The second error is: app tries to connect as a non-existing user.

Comment: What did you run that produced the error ?

Comment: appended to question, due to lack of formatting in comment section

Comment: i think this has to do with PGDATA , not being in the expected place

Comment: There's an obvious discrepancy between the very first error listed and the very last error (under *additionally*).  This points to there being difficulty locating the Unix socket. The first is looking for a socket `/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432` and the second `/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432`.  Check where this is supposed to be found by looking for the field "unix_socket_directory" in postgresql.conf (probably located in /etc/postgresql/<version>/<cluster>/).  Then check it's actually there by doing a `ls -lA socket_dir`.

Answer (score 1):

Fascinating error.  It looks like your user is able to connect to sockets properly but the postgres user is not.    I find this very odd.  My guess is that there is something wrong with the profile of the postgres user.

where I would recommend starting is with a printenv as both your normal user and the postgres user and compare them.  Particularly look at PGPORT and PGHOST variables as these can determine socket location.  This is the first place to start.

Secondly you can check the postgresql.conf for the socket directory and set PGHOST to the absolute directory path.  That would likely fix your problem, but something is messed up on the user account level on your system.